# Linq - Count <li> tags in a block of HTML

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to count the number of `<li>` tags in a text field using Linq with Entity Framework 4, that runs as a query against the database rather than in memory?

Comment: I don't see what EF4 has to do with HTML...?

Comment: I'm storing records, which have a Description field, which is in HTML... EF4 becomes relevent because only a subset of operations can be translated into SQL operations that happen on the database - anything outside that subset means you have to pull all records into memory for processing

Comment: So you want an EF query that translates into SQL that counts those li's database-side? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yep that would be the holy grail - I also can't think of a way it would be done - maybe with Regex if there's a way to combine them with Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid my answer isn't an answer, it's a workaround. I'll leave the question open a week or so because it'd be great if someone far smarter than me has some miracle way of doing this.

I called `.AsEnumerable()` on my query, after applying as many other filters as possible, and then processed the results in memory. I actually used `.Where(Function(x) x.Description.Split("<li>").Count > 3)` as my in-memory filter, on the grounds that valid HTML isn't always valid XML - I can't necessarily trust my users to provide perfect XHTML compliant content, but that doesn't mean it won't display correctly for their purposes.

Luckily in the business context - quality control of newly added descriptions - the number of things being checked is suitably small that after applying all the other filters there isn't a stupidly big number of things to process.

Answer (score 0):

if your html block is valid that mean is xml block. And you can try to use Linq to XML.
Other way you should to pars your html manual.

Comment: Ok, sorry, should clarify the question - I'm asking if there's a way to do this against a whole load of database records, without pulling them all into memory

Comment: -1: That's not true. Valid HTML is not always valid XML, except when you we are talking about XHTML. But there is not current standard for XHTML, work on XHTML 2.0 has been stopped.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction, using Linq-to-XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("your html");
var liCount = doc.Descendants("input").Descendants("li").Count();
```

Comment: Ok feared as much, that works for Linq-to-Objects, but doesn't translate to Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities

Comment: @Richard: if you want -to-SQL or to-Entities you are basically saying you want (!!!?) to parse HTML in the Database. That's sick.

Comment: OTOH: I know with SQLServer you can write Stored Procedures in C#. Perhaps database functions too? In that case, you can have your cake and eat it too :) _it would_ still _be sick_...

Comment: The actual requirement is: 1. store descriptions in HTML; 2. identify records with "short" descriptions, i.e. less than 3 bullet points. I had thought of normalising it out so that 1 Product has * description points - but that's hideous as well!

Comment: @Richard: Maybe you should redesign your database and not store the html, instead just store the actual information. That way you are free to render the information any way you want.

Comment: Trouble is, the requirement to use HTML is so that users can format descriptions (bold, underline, italic etc) as well as use bullets - not to mention getting into nested bullet points, numbered lists etc. Designing a database schema that copes with the nuances of HTML, with parent elements, child elements etc isn't feasible. I thought of trying that though, where 1 Description has * DescriptionPoints, but it can't cope with the other stuff sadly.

Comment: @RichardW1001: That is disgusting. This is classic mixing of presentation and data and is just a recipe for a joyless, soulless existence.

Comment: Yep - hey, I don't choose the requirements, I just try my best to fulfil them as painlessly as possible. I can understand what they want and why they want it, but yeah it's not pretty at all!

Comment: Also, it's not really about "presentation" per se - the question is basically "look for database records where a specified field contains more than a specified number of instances of a specified substring" - the fact that that substring is actually a HTML tag and the text in the field is a block of HTML isn't really relevent

Comment: @RichardW1001: You said yourself it is done in that way so they can format ("(bold, underline, italic etc)") descriptions (data). That IS presentation mixed with data.

Comment: @RichardW1001 @Jason - hey guys, stop arguing and upvote my answer ;-)